# image downloader MalformedURLException

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to build an app which takes a link for an image and downloads it from the web. Whenever I rn my app it gives me a MalformedUrlException: Protocol not formed: url ICan anyone tell me what Im doing wrong. I am new to android so I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

```
     package com.img.imagedwnloader;

     import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileOutputStream;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.InputStream;
     import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
     import java.net.URL;
     import java.net.URLConnection;

     import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.os.Environment;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static Button dwnload;
    static EditText link;
    static TextView textv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dwnload = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bstrtD);
    link = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.etlink);
    textv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvUpdate);
    dwnload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textv.setText("click");

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    textv.setText("thread");
                    File storedwn = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File file = new File (storedwn, "downloadFile.jpg");
                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    try{
                        textv.setText("try");
                        String linkt = link.getText().toString();
                        URL url = new URL (linkt);
                        textv.setText(link.getText().toString());
                        URLConnection urlconnect = url.openConnection();
                        InputStream is = urlconnect.getInputStream();
                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream (is);
                        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                        int current = 0;
                        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                                baf.append((byte) current);
                        }
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                        fos.close();
                        textv.setText("Download Completed in" + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                     textv.setText("Error: " + e);
                }



                }

        /*      private void downloadVid() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{
                    URL url = new URL (link.getText().toString());
                    textv.setText(link.getText());
                    HttpURLConnection urlconnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlconnect.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlconnect.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlconnect.connect();
                    File storedwn = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File file = new File (storedwn, "downloadFile.avi");

                    } catch (Exception e){
                        textv.setText("Failed!");
                    }
                }

            }).start();;
        } */



    });
}

}
```

Comment: What is the link, does it include http or https?

Comment: Nope. The link does not have http or https..

Comment: Could you please tell us what is the start of your URL like? www.something, for example. I think you have to specify the protocol. http:// or https://

Comment: I tried doing that and now it gives me an SSL exception.

Comment: my link is https://http://youcrypt.com/assets/images/osx.jpg

Comment: Could you show the Exception you are getting? It must be in another line now.

Comment: You have to put that code inside an AsyncTask. You can't do Networking operations in the UI THread.